# Присваивание массиву, элементов псевдомассива arguments

Tags: javascript

Доброе утро, господа. Код функции обертки складывает в массив `argsArr` элементы из `agruments`  функции `sum`.

```
"use strict";

var argsArr = [];

function funcLog(f, argsArr) {
  return function() {
    var wrapper = f.apply(this, arguments);
    var argsArrLocal = [].slice.call(arguments);
    for (var i = 0; i < argsArrLocal.length; i++) {
      argsArr.push(argsArrLocal[i]);
    }

    return wrapper;
  };
}

function sum(a,b) {
  alert(a+b+b);
}

sum = funcLog(sum, argsArr);
sum(2,3);
alert(argsArr);
```

Первый вариант кода, был таким.

```
"use strict";

var argsArr = [];

function funcLog(f, argsArr) {
  return function() {
    var wrapper = f.apply(this, arguments);
    argsArr = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return wrapper;
  };
}

function sum(a,b) {
  alert(a+b+b);
}

sum = funcLog(sum, argsArr);
sum(2,3);
alert(argsArr);
```

Но, он не работал. Массив, `argsArr`, не перезаписывался, а почему так происходило я не знаю. Я подозреваю, что где-то ошибся, но сути ошибки не пойму. Направьте на путь истинный.

Comment: а почему не срабатывает присваивание? все отлично срабатывает

Comment: Может быть ты просто ожидаешь какой-то другой результат?

Comment: argsArr =[].slice.call(arguments);

Comment: Без var, а то получится создание локальной переменной.

Comment: и? что значат эти комментарии? все работает именно так как и должно. Что именно тебя не устраивает?

Comment: Первый вариант был таким.

Comment: var argsArr = [];

function funcLog(f, argsArr) {
  return function() {
    var wrapper = f.apply(this, arguments);
    argsArr = [].slice.call(arguments);
    
    return wrapper;
  };
}

function sum(a,b) {
  alert(a+b+b);
}

sum = funcLog(sum, argsArr);
sum(2,3);
alert(argsArr);

Comment: код в комментариях нечитаем. Перенеси **все необходимое** в вопрос. И кроме куска кода добавляй описание что это за кусок, что он делает, и что ты ожидал он должен делать

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в неверном использовании функции.

```
function funcLog(f, argsArr) {
```

Как можно заметить имя второго параметра *argsArr*, любые действия с этим именем *внутри функции* производятся с параметром, а не одноименной глобальной переменной.

Самый простой способ сделать первый код рабочим - просто убрать этот параметр из определения функции

```
function funcLog(f) {
```

---

Почему это работает во втором случае?

Так как глобальный массив передается в функцию, данный параметр *ссылается* на глобальную переменную, поэтому при вызове методов меняющих непосредственно объект изменения отображались и на глобальной переменной.

При присваивании же, происходила просто смена ссылка для параметра.

Comment: Если бы я не знал этого раньше - я бы так и не понял что тут написано.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, прям совсем-совсем непонятно? Вроде основная мысль - убрать параметр - ясно прослеживается?

Comment: А что делать если надо будет собирать аргументы в два разных массива?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а где автор хочет собирать в два разных массива? :-) у него оба варианта все кладут в один.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну и на сколько я понимаю достаточно перенести этот массив внутрь функции

Comment: Спасибо Вам Grundy большое. Как обычно, спотыкаюсь на азах.

Comment: @AlexanderKorinskiy, если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым (нажмите галку под рейтингом ответа). Проголосовать за ответ (треугольник вверх) тоже будет не лишним)